# Shifting/jumping on an element after transform

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm working on a big project and I used transform before only few times, so I don't have too much experience. This time the client has many requests regarding the effects.

I have an `#item`, inside it there's a button and a transparent `div`. On hover the `opacity` changes to `0.8` on the transparent `div`, and the button appears with `transform`, from the top. The problem is when I hover on the `div`, the button appears but after few ms you can see the button size increase and the text moves few pixels. (Firefox 42.0 - OSX)

I tried few solutions to fix it, but no luck, I really don't know why is it happening. (`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`)

I'm lucky, because this time I reproduced it in a single file, and I don't need to copy the 100kb css. :)

The code is really simple. I really appreciate that if you can give me some guidelines, tutorials, or a solution to fix it.

I added the code below, but it's also available at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8gm1pfz/1/).

```css
#item {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
}

a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#item:hover a {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
}

#overlay {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

#item:hover #overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="item">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <a href="">Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Might not be helpfull... but; I ran the code trough IE/FF/Chrome/Safari and none of these browsers display the issue you are having. Is this problem only occurring in your complete script or also in the fiddle?

Comment: I just tried it in Firefox 41 (OS/X) and I didn't see any problem. I then upgraded to Firefox 42 and now I'm seeing it!

Comment: @Sjef92 on JSFiddle.

Comment: @MarkPlewis it looks like you should care about this in the future after firefox upgrade, sorry. :)

Comment: your example works pretty fine on the newest FF(42) and Ch(46) (Win10)

Comment: Thank, unfortunately on osx it doesn't smooth

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS is "expensive" to render. You can add this transform hack to kick your GPU into helping process this smoothly. It tells the browser there will be a z-axis transform (of zero, which is actually not a transform), so the computer uses the GPU in addition to the CPU. This added power often helps with visual glitches. It is a hack though strictly speaking :)

Sass:

```
.gpu {
  @include vendor(transform, translateZ(0));
}
```

CSS

```
.gpu {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help, because I use Z axis transform too for centering.

Comment: You're centering on the Z axis? I conceptually understand this on X and Y, but now you're blowing my mind.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're saying. I would literally use this code and add the .gpu class (with your code above you could comma chain I believe). Your translate CSS above is just on X and Y.

Comment: Sorry, you are true. I mean X axis. I added the class for the button, here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/e8gm1pfz/2/